# date method in eloquent querybuilder

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have this raw query and i want to use it in eloquent query builder
but seems i cant use date method in eloquent and gave me this error im new in eloquent. what is the problem:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date(prizes.created_at), user_id' in 'group statement' (SQL: select user_id,COUNT(user_id), date(created_at) from `prizes` group by `date(prizes`.`created_at), user_id` having `user_id` = 1 order by `date(created_at)` desc)
```

raw SQL:

```
SELECT
user_id,COUNT(user_id), DATE(created_at) FROM prizes
GROUP BY DATE(prizes.created_at), user_id
HAVING user_id = 1
ORDER BY DATE(created_at) DESC
limit 2
```

Eloquent:

```
$points = \App\Prize::selectRaw('user_id,COUNT(user_id), date(created_at)')
    ->groupBy("date(prizes.created_at), user_id")
    ->orderBy("date(created_at)","DESC")
    ->having("user_id","=",1)
    ->get();
```

what is the the cleanest and best form??

Comment: what about [attribute casting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Laravel tries to parse all strings as tables. This means it will add the string between `.

To avoid this, you can put the string in a [`DB:raw()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#raw-expressions) function to let Laravel know not to parse this string and send it as-is to the database.

```
->orderBy(\DB::raw("date(created_at)"), "DESC")
```

Or use the raw method for ordering:

```
->orderByRaw('date(created_at) desc')
```

Comment: what is the cleanest form without using raw?

Comment: I would say using the raw methods. However, not every query builder function has a raw method.